# Do something if mySQL query is successful

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

I have the following mySQL query:

```
$content = mysqli_query($dblink, "SELECT * FROM passwordrecovery WHERE code = '$formcode'");

            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($content)) {
                $db_username = $row['username'];
                $db_email = $row['email'];
                $db_code = $row['code'];
            }
```

I would like to add an IF statement somewhere here to check whether the query is successful but I am not sure where.

Basically, I have a form where a user can insert a code (sent by email) to retrieve their password. But they might make a mistake and enter a code that doesn't exist in the database and I would like to account for such a situation and throw back an error. I am just not sure how to do it?

Comment: Please add a tag for the language you're using (perl?)

Comment: Sorry its php. I have added the tag.

Comment: @Truth that is mysqli, albeit procedural, not OO mysqli. Part about prepared statements stands though

Comment: @Michael: Didn't see that, my bad (too many people using `mysql_*` I immediately saw it :D) carry on. Though if $formcode is by some means from user input, you should be using prepared statements.

Comment: @Truth: Thanks very much for the input and criticism, I am a newb and learning, so I appreciate it :) Although you did confuse me immensely when you said I should be using mysqli_* :) Prepared statements is something I will look into, but I am under time stress for my course project so I have to go with what I know for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On query failure, `$content` will be `FALSE` rather than a result resource.  Check that it is not false.  If they entered a non-existent code, you would get no rows back, so check for at least one row via [`mysqli_num_rows()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php).

```
$content = mysqli_query($dblink, "SELECT * FROM passwordrecovery WHERE code = '$formcode'");

if ($content) {
    // Check for at least one row returned
  if (mysqli_num_rows($content) < 1) {
    // Invalid lookup, show error to user
  }
  // Got a row back, so query was valid
  else {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($content)) {
      $db_username = $row['username'];
      $db_email = $row['email'];
      $db_code = $row['code'];
    }
  } 
}
else {
  // Query failure - display error to user
  // and check mysqli_error() internally for debugging
}
```

We assume you have already properly escaped `$formcode` via `mysqli_real_escape_string($formcode)`.

Comment: false is only for syntax errors and db communications problems. A query which returns no rows is not a failure. it's just a 0-row result set. That's why there the num_rows() functions

Comment: Sorry excuse my ignorance, but is not the first IF statement redundant now due to the 2nd IF statement where we check for at least 1 row?

Comment: @PartisanEntity No it isn't redundant, because the first one checks for the possibility of a syntax error which would prevent you from being able to fetch rows or check the number of rows returned. If you had database connection problem, for example, or the table queried didn't exist.  It's a best practice.